# Using Lombok's SuperBuilder with Hibernate Validator (jakarta.validation.x) annotation on a container type leads to "Type mismatch"

Tags: java, testing, lombok, hibernate-validator

I have a class `ActivitiesModel` which uses Lombok's `SuperBuilder`.

```java
import jakarta.validation.NotBlank;

// other imports and statements omitted for brevity.

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ActivitiesModel {
    public static final String ACTIVITIES_NOT_NULL_MESSAGE = "Activities cannot be null";
    public static final String ACTIVITY_NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE = "Activity cannot be blank";

    @NotNull(message = ACTIVITIES_NOT_NULL_MESSAGE)
    private List<@NotBlank(message = ACTIVITY_NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE) String> activities;
}
```

I am using this builder to create an object of `ActivitiesModel`, and then validating it using Hibernate's `Validator` interface:

```java
// Somewhere else in the application.

// Create an object using the builder method.
ActivitiesModel activitiesModel = ActivitiesModel.builder()
                                    .activities(List.of("hello", "world")) // <----- Point A
                                    .build();

// Validate the object using Hibernate's validator.
validator.validate(activitiesModel);
```

However, running this code gives me the following error:

```bash
java.lang.Error: 
Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to List<E>
```

The stack trace seems to be pointing at `Point A`.

I have tried the following approaches:

1. Replacing the `@SuperBuilder` with `@Builder` and `@AllArgsConstructor`.
2. Replacing the `message` attribute with a string literal instead of a `static final` variable, i.e:

```java
private List<@NotBlank(message = "Activity cannot be blank") String> activities;
```

1st approach seems to fix this error, however, it's not something I can use as I need to extend the builder functionality to a subclass of `ActivitiesModel`. Also, this issue is also present in another `abstract` class, so the super builder functionality for parent classes is definitely required.

2nd approach also works in solving the error. However, going with it is a bit problematic because I then need to have the same message string in the validation test for this model class, which is something I would like to avoid as it duplicates the string.

Another thing to note is that this error only seems to occur in the presence of an annotation on the generic type parameter of the container, which is `NotBlank` in this case. It is not influenced by any annotations which are present directly on the field itself (`NotNull` in this case).

So, all in all, these are the questions that I would like to get some answers to:

1. Somehow, Lombok is able to figure out the types in case of a string literal but not in case of a `static final String`. Why is that?
2. Am I going about this totally wrong? The problem occurs because I'm trying to store the message string in a variable, and I'm trying to re-use the same variable at two places: the annotation's `message` attribute, and in the validation test for the model class. Should I not be checking for the presence of the message in my validation tests, but be checking for something else instead?

Comment: I built this locally and it is working fine for me.  Is your code failing to reach the validator? If you comment out the validator, does it compile and run fine?  Also, what version of Java and Spring-Boot are you using?

Comment: So I tried the same with a clean project, and it worked with that. One thing led to another and I ended up narrowing the problem down to the fact that it has something to do with build cache. If I clean it, and then try to run it, it works fine. However, after making some changes here and there, it fails again, and then I need to clean build cache again.

To answer your question, I am running Java 17, and not using Spring Boot but Quarkus (2.13.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this later on, the research for this issue has led me to believe that comparing message strings in tests is not the way to go about writing validation test cases. Another downside to this approach is that you might have different validation messages for different locales. In that case, the message string itself might be a template e.g. `my.message.key` with its values in a `ResourceBundle` provided to Hibernate, i.e. files such as `ValidationMessages.properties` and `ValidationMessages_de.properties`.

In such a scenario, you could compare message for one locale in your validation test case, however, a better approach might be to check the annotation and the field for which the validation has failed. We can get both of these pieces of information via the `ConstraintViolation` and subsequently the `ConstraintDescriptor` types, provided by Hibernate. This way we can circumvent checking the message itself, but rely on the actual validation annotation which has failed.

As for the solution to this question, it seems it was a build cache issue. Cleaning maven's build cache results in this code working perfectly fine, but VSCode still seems to have an issue. For now, I will choose to ignore that.